# Web scrapping gives different output every time

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page_url = "http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=-1&IsNodeId=1&Description=GTX&bop=And&Page=1&PageSize=36&order=BESTMATCH"
uclient = request.urlopen(page_url) #open a webclient
html_page = uclient.read()
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page,"html.parser") 
uclient.close()
containers = page_soup.find_all("div",{"class" :"item-cell"}) 
title_list = []
for contain in containers:
    title = contain.select("img")[0]["title"]
    print(title)# for troubleshooting
    print(len(title_list)) #for troubleshooting
    title_list.append(title)
print(title_list)
```

Can someone pls help in troubleshooting? Everytime i run the code , once it returns 12 values sometimes 28 , sometimes 30 and then it gives an error .:

```
Input In [67], in <cell line: 16>()
     15 title_list = []
     16 for contain in containers:
---> 17     title = contain.select("img")[0]["title"]
     18     print(title)# for troubleshooting
     19     print(len(title_list)) #for troubleshooting

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py:1519, in Tag.__getitem__(self, key)
   1516 def __getitem__(self, key):
   1517     """tag[key] returns the value of the 'key' attribute for the Tag,
   1518     and throws an exception if it's not there."""
-> 1519     return self.attrs[key]

KeyError: 'title'
```

Comment: It's a dynamic web site, it returns different results.

Comment: even if its a dynamic website I'm saving the beautiful set result in a variable which is a list and then iterating it through it ! I just fetch the contents once and not every time . Hence dynamic or no it shouldn't make a difference i guess. Correct me if m wrong ! The containers list variable has the requested html tags , and i do a for loop on it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, it looks like you're trying to print out a list of products on the page. I find this code much better at returning those titles.

```
containers = page_soup.select(".item-title") 
titles = [c.text for c in containers if len(c.text) > 25]
```

I used the select method to find every class instance of '.item-title' instead, and grabbed the text from that element for each line.

Sample output

```
MSI Ventus GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER 6GB GDDR6 PCI Express 3.0 x16 Video Card GTX 1660 SUPER VENTUS XS OC
EVGA GeForce GTX 1650 SC ULTRA GAMING, 04G-P4-1057-KR, 4GB GDDR5, Dual Fan, Metal Backplate
MSI Gaming GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER 6GB GDDR6 PCI Express 3.0 x16 Video Card GTX 1660 SUPER GAMING X
ASUS TUF Gaming GeForce GTX 1650 OC Edition 4GB GDDR6 PCI Express 3.0 Video Card TUF-GTX1650-O4GD6-P-GAMING
MSI Ventus GeForce GTX 1650 4GB GDDR6 PCI Express 3.0 x16 Video Card GTX 1650 D6 VENTUS XS
ASUS Dual GeForce RTX 3050 8GB GDDR6 PCI Express 4.0 Video Card DUAL-RTX3050-O8G
```

Comment: Hi Jackie thanks alot, let me check if this works !

Comment: Hi , Jackie worked like a charm ! Thanks alot :) Is there any particular doc u refer for bs4 ? and for webscrapping in particular?

Comment: Pretty much just this: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: @aishwaryamurali I forgot to mention that the select function takes css class selectors as arguments. If you've worked with css before, you'll know that a leading `.` represents a class, explaining the leading period in my `select()` argument.

Comment: HI thank you so much, but i did read the doc to check how fetch a class or a particular id (using a # sign for id) . My only concern is how different is the select and find_all method. How it worked so easily with the select but the find_all method didn't give the desired output back !